# How do I replace '<p>' with '<p>\n' and '</p>' with '\n</p>' using sed?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, text-processing

I have following file and I want to replace `<p>` with `<p>\n` and `</p>` with `\n</p>` using `sed`.

My input file contains the following lines:

```html
<p>This is home.</p>
<p>These are fruits.</p>
```

My output file should be like the file given below.

```html
<p>
This is home.
</p>
<p>
These are fruits.
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ sed 's/<p>/&\n/g;s/<\/p>/\n&/g' file 
<p>
This is home.
</p>
<p>
These are fruits.
</p>
```

The `&` on the right hand side of the substitution operator is expanded to whatever was matched by the left hand side. So, in `s/<p>/&\n/`, `&` will be expanded to `<p>` and in `s/<\/p>/\n&/`, it will be expanded to `</p>`. The `g` (`s///g`) makes `sed` replace all occurrences, so it will also work if you have more than one `<p>` or `</p>` on a single line.

Comment: The `g` flag is missing in the first `s///` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
$ cat file.txt 
<p>This is home.</p>
<p>These are fruits.</p>

$ sed -r 's/^([^>]+>)([^<]+)(<.*)/\1\n\2\n\3/' file.txt 
<p>
This is home.
</p>
<p>
These are fruits.
</p>
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if there are more than one set of `<p>` and `</p>` on a line and will also fail if there are any other HTML tags between the `<p>` and `</p>`. For example `<p>one paragraph,<br> two lines</p>`. Finally, it will replace _any_ tag that is at the beginning of the line with itself and a newline.

Comment: @terdon Hey guru..howdy? this was just to answer the very example..formatting XML using `sed` is a bad idea anyway..